# Google Sheets, Sort table based on unique values in a single column

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I am currently trying to use google sheets to sort a table based on the unique values found in only two of the columns.

What I want to happen is that columns **A (Brand)** and **B (Dimensions)** are both checked for unique values, **removing any duplicate data**.

The problem is using these two columns to filter and show the rest of table. I can't managed to achieve it.

***Original Data***

[image]

***What is should look like after being culled***

[image]

.

Comment: Could you take your data and put it here so it is not hidden behind a link?

Comment: Sounds like you needs a common JavaScript bubble sort.

Comment: You can used query, group by brand and dimension, min(cost) and min(other info)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Query function:

```
=query(A1:D8,"select A, B, min(C), min(D)  group by A, B",1)
```

[image: Example]
[Example spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xitc4yxDFD9K-vbWj9zO4DL6BgKrc4Y3Ere2bwrhXb8/edit#gid=0)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SORT(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(SORTN(
 IF(A2:C<>"", {"♦"&A2:A&"♦"&B2:B, "♦"&C2:D}, ), 99^99, 2, 1, 1))
 ,,99^99)), "♦"), 2, 1))
```

[image: 0]